# How to close a fancybox element in Google Chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to close a popup content in some web pages via Chrome developer console.

For example:
When I open http://www.cw.com.tw for the first time, it will show a `fancybox-content` element.
[image]

So I will have to click the "close button" of the advertisement in order to read to article.

This website is trustable, but for some websites, if I don't want to click that element for some security concerns, **how can I close that popup content and remove the grey layer without click the `fancybox-close` button**.

In another word, how can I know which function it triggers when I click that `fancybox-close` button?

I tried inspected the element, and deleted the `fancybox-content`node directly. But it didn't help very much.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have read the document first though,

```
$.fancybox.close()
```

should do the trick.

FYI, the API documentation here.

http://fancybox.net/api